# Query to find average of rate per day per account

Tags: aggregate, average, teradata, window-functions, teradatasql

I have a requirement to find the average of a rate field. The average should be based know a date field, account number and product code. I need to use this query inside an insert..select statement.

Insert into tablename
Rate
Select
Avg(rate.....
From
Tablenane

Example

Acctid | date  |   prodcode | rate

101  |  31-12-2023 | A100 | 0.045

101  |  31-12-2023 | A100 | 0.045

101  |  30-11-2023 | A101 | 0.035

101  |  30-11-2023 | A101 | 0.025

102  |  30-11-2023 | A123 | 0.055

102  |  30-11-2023 | A123 | 0.045

- Output

Acctid | date |   prodcode | rate

101  | 31-12-2023 | A100   | 0.045

101  | 30-11-2023 | A101   | 0.03

102  | 30-11-2023 | A123   | 0.05

Please help.

Select sum(rate) over(partition by acctid,date,prodcode order by date)/count(rate) over (partition by acctid,date,prodcode)

This gives

Output

rate

0.045

0.045

0.03

0.03

0.05

0.05

Comment: Looks like aggregation: `Select acctid,date,prodcode, avg(rate)  from mytable group by 1,2,3`